# Intergrating jBPM 5.4 with Spring-Hibernate for Transaction Management?

Tags: spring, hibernate, transactions, jbpm

I have created a simple process using jBPM 5.4. I want to use transaction managment provided by the Spring-Hibernate.
What are the required changes and configurations for that ?
also 
What is the step by step process?

Answer (score 1):

Check the documentation here: http://docs.jboss.org/jbpm/v5.4/userguide/ch.integration.html#d0e7839

There are some examples, like https://github.com/droolsjbpm/droolsjbpm-integration/blob/5.5.0.Final/drools-container/drools-spring/src/test/java/org/drools/container/spring/beans/persistence/JPASingleSessionCommandServiceFactoryTest.java

Basically, you can use a Spring configuration file to configure your persistence, transactions and ksessions (if you want to), and then inject them into your code for usage there.

Kris